# Get data type from closed workbook cell and vary action accordingly

Tags: vba, excel

I'm collecting metric values from many different worksheets in one overview sheet which will be used for generating a PowerBI dashboard.

Below is my code, i'm new to vba so it's probably not so elegant, but works for what i need, except for one thing.

Some of the metric values in these sheets are integers, others have data type percentage.
If the value in the metric sheet has number format %, for example "10" formatted as %, it gets taken as 0,1 with the current code i have. I would like to multiply these percentages with 100 and add this number in the overview sheet. But I have difficulties finding out how i can extract the data type and if a percentage, multiply with 100, and if no percentage, get the value as is. Would anyone be able to help with that?

Many thanks in advance -

```
Function HasSheet(fPath As String, fName As String, sheetName As String)
On Error Resume Next
Dim f As String

f = "'" & fPath & "[" & fName & "]" & sheetName & "'!R1C1"

HasSheet = Not IsError(Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(f))
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    HasSheet = False
End If
On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Sub CollectMetrics()

Dim id As Integer
Dim Ind As String

Dim MetricName As String
Dim Include1 As String
Dim Include2 As String

Dim Segment As String
Dim file As String
Dim filepath As String
Dim filename As String
Dim s As Boolean

Dim D As Date
Dim MonthNbr As Integer

Set sh1 = Worksheets("Metrics")
Set sh2 = Worksheets("Metadata")


NumRows = sh1.Range("A1", sh1.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    For id = 2 To NumRows

        MetricName = sh1.Range("A" & id).Value
        Include1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(MetricName, sh2.Range("B2:L100"), 9, True)
        Include2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(MetricName, sh2.Range("B2:L100"), 10, True)
        Ind = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(MetricName, sh2.Range("B2:L100"), 2, True)
        filename = Ind & " " & MetricName & " 2018.xlsx"

        If Include1 = "auto" And Include2 = "yes" Then

                 Segment = sh1.Range("B" & id).Value

                 file = "='https://xxx/[" & filename & "]" & Segment
                 filepath = "https://xxx/"


                 s = HasSheet(filepath, filename, Segment)

                        If s Then

                             D = sh1.Range("C" & id).Value
                             MonthNbr = Month(D)

                             sh1.Range("D" & id).Value = file & "'!D" & (MonthNbr + 13)
                             sh1.Range("E" & id).Value = file & "'!E" & (MonthNbr + 13)
                             sh1.Range("F" & id).Value = file & "'!F" & (MonthNbr + 13)
                             sh1.Range("G" & id).Value = file & "'!G" & (MonthNbr + 13)
                             sh1.Range("J" & id).Value = file & "'!D" & (MonthNbr + 40)
                             sh1.Range("K" & id).Value = file & "'!E" & (MonthNbr + 40)
                             sh1.Range("L" & id).Value = file & "'!F" & (MonthNbr + 40)
                             sh1.Range("M" & id).Value = file & "'!G" & (MonthNbr + 40)
                             sh1.Range("O" & id).Value = "values updated on " & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yy")
                         Else
                             sh1.Range("O" & id).Value = "sheet available but segment missing"
                        End If
                ElseIf Include2 = "no" Then
                 sh1.Range("O" & id).Value = "metric set to not yet include"
                ElseIf Include1 = "manual" Then
                 sh1.Range("O" & id).Value = "metric to be manually updated"
             End If

    Next
MsgBox (" Update completed! ")
End Sub
```

Comment: You can examine the `.numberformat` property of the range object and see if it includes an unescaped `%` .  It is a string, so simple `Instr` should suffice.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980484/checking-data-types-in-a-range

Comment: Values to verify from: file & "'!D" & (MonthNbr + 13) for example...

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid multiplying a percentage by 100 and adding a percent symbol, if there's the option to do it the "right way".

It's not a huge problem in this case, it's just better to create good habits.  (And just for the record, the reason `10%` gets taken as `0,1` is because **`10%` *is* `0,1`**.

Nonetheless, we need an easy way to display it as a percentage instead of a fraction of 1 (when applicable), and as with many tasks in Excel, there are multiple ways to accomplish the same thing.

**This way took me the least thought:**

```
Range("B1") = Range("A1") 'copies the value
Range("B1").NumberFormat = Range("A1") .NumberFormat 'copies the number format.
```

**Changes I made:**

- The "cleanest" way to do this was with a small sub called `copyNumber` and adjusting the affected lines to use the new procedure.
- I tidied indentation - which *is* important for organization and readability.
- I added `Option Explicit` which is a good idea to have at the beginning of every module, to help recognize oversights such as...
- `sh1` and `sh2` were not declared as `Worksheet`s, so I added `Dim` statements for them - but squished them onto a line shared with their `Set` statements with `:` colons.

The other changes I made were purely cosmetic and more of a matter of perference, and obviously if you don't like those changes, don't use them.  :-)

- I got rid of the `ElseIf`'s - I don't like them for the same reason indentation is important.
- I used With..End statements to remove repetitive code (like `Sh1.` and `Application.WorksheetFunction.`)
- I squished the variable declaration (`Dim` statements) from "a page" into 3 lines.

---

### Adjusted Code:

```
Option Explicit

Function HasSheet(fPath As String, fName As String, sheetName As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim f As String
    f = "'" & fPath & "[" & fName & "]" & sheetName & "'!R1C1"
    HasSheet = Not IsError(Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(f))
    If Err Then HasSheet = False
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Sub copyNumber(rgeSrc As Range, rgeDest As Range)
    rgeDest.Value = rgeSrc.Value                ' copy number
    rgeDest.NumberFormat = rgeSrc.NumberFormat  ' copy number format
End Sub

Sub CollectMetrics()

    Dim MetricName As String, Segment As String, Ind As String, Include1 As String, Include2 As String
    Dim file As String, filePath As String, fileName As String
    Dim MonthNbr As Integer, id As Integer, numRows As Integer

    Dim sh1 As Worksheet: Set sh1 = Worksheets("Metrics")
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet: Set sh2 = Worksheets("Metadata")
    With sh1
        numRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

        For id = 2 To numRows
            MetricName = Range("A" & id)
            With Application.WorksheetFunction
                Include1 = .VLookup(MetricName, sh2.Range("B2:L100"), 9, True)
                Include2 = .VLookup(MetricName, sh2.Range("B2:L100"), 10, True)
                Ind = .VLookup(MetricName, sh2.Range("B2:L100"), 2, True)
            End With
            fileName = Ind & " " & MetricName & " 2018.xlsx"

            If Include1 = "auto" And Include2 = "yes" Then
                Segment = Range("B" & id)
                file = "='https://xxx/[" & fileName & "]" & Segment
                filePath = "https://xxx/"

                If HasSheet(filePath, fileName, Segment) Then
                    MonthNbr = Month(Range("C" & id))
                    copyNumber .Range("D" & id), Range(file & "'!D" & (MonthNbr + 13))
                    copyNumber .Range("E" & id), Range(file & "'!E" & (MonthNbr + 13))
                    copyNumber .Range("F" & id), Range(file & "'!F" & (MonthNbr + 13))
                    copyNumber .Range("G" & id), Range(file & "'!G" & (MonthNbr + 13))
                    copyNumber .Range("J" & id), Range(file & "'!D" & (MonthNbr + 40))
                    copyNumber .Range("K" & id), Range(file & "'!E" & (MonthNbr + 40))
                    copyNumber .Range("L" & id), Range(file & "'!F" & (MonthNbr + 40))
                    copyNumber .Range("M" & id), Range(file & "'!G" & (MonthNbr + 40))
                    Range("O" & id) = "Values updated on " & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yy")
                Else
                    Range("O" & id) = "Sheet available but segment missing"
                End If
            Else
                If Include2 = "no" Then
                    Range("O" & id) = "Metric set to not yet include"
                Else
                    If Include1 = "manual" Then Range("O" & id) = "Metric to be manually updated"
                End If
            End If
        Next id
    End With
    MsgBox "Update completed!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for reworking the code and helping me forward. I think destination and source are to be switched, but in both cases this codes gives a 1004 error on the copynumber .Range... line. It seems to be in the way the source file is referred to. Do you have any idea how to point to it properly? I fully agree that 10% is correctly represented through 0.1, but I need it to be shown as 10 in the power bi dashboard, and there mixtures in number format cannot be handled in one column.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is looking for this approach in future, here is the final code i used:

```
    Option Explicit

Function HasSheet(fPath As String, fName As String, sheetName As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim f As String
    f = "'" & fPath & "[" & fName & "]" & sheetName & "'!R1C1"
    HasSheet = Not IsError(Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(f))
    If Err Then HasSheet = False
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Sub CollectMetrics()

    Dim MetricName As String, Segment As String, Ind As String, Include1 As String, Include2 As String, Include3 As String
    Dim file As String, filePath As String, fileName As String
    Dim MonthNbr As Integer, id As Integer, numRows As Integer

    Dim sh1 As Worksheet: Set sh1 = Worksheets("Metrics")
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet: Set sh2 = Worksheets("Metadata")
    With sh1
        numRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

        For id = 2 To numRows
            MetricName = Range("A" & id)
            With Application.WorksheetFunction
                Include1 = .VLookup(MetricName, sh2.Range("B2:L100"), 9, True)
                Include2 = .VLookup(MetricName, sh2.Range("B2:L100"), 10, True)
                Include3 = .VLookup(MetricName, sh2.Range("B2:L100"), 11, True)
                Ind = .VLookup(MetricName, sh2.Range("B2:L100"), 2, True)
            End With
            fileName = Ind & " " & MetricName & " 2018.xlsx"

            If Include1 = "auto" And Include2 = "yes" Then
                Segment = Range("B" & id)

                file = "='https://xxxx/[" & fileName & "]" & Segment
                filePath = "https://xxxx/"

                 If HasSheet(filePath, fileName, Segment) Then

                    MonthNbr = Month(Range("C" & id))

                    sh1.Range("D" & id).Value = file & "'!D" & (MonthNbr + 13)
                    sh1.Range("E" & id).Value = file & "'!E" & (MonthNbr + 13)
                    sh1.Range("F" & id).Value = file & "'!F" & (MonthNbr + 13)
                    sh1.Range("G" & id).Value = file & "'!G" & (MonthNbr + 13)

                    sh1.Range("H" & id).Value = file & "'!B" & (MonthNbr + 13) 'Actuals KPI Index
                        Select Case sh1.Range("H" & id).Value
                        Case "R"
                        sh1.Range("H" & id).Value = "3"
                        Case "Y"
                        sh1.Range("H" & id).Value = "2"
                        Case "G"
                        sh1.Range("H" & id).Value = "1"
                        End Select

                    sh1.Range("I" & id).Value = file & "'!D" & (MonthNbr + 40)
                    sh1.Range("J" & id).Value = file & "'!E" & (MonthNbr + 40)
                    sh1.Range("K" & id).Value = file & "'!F" & (MonthNbr + 40)
                    sh1.Range("L" & id).Value = file & "'!G" & (MonthNbr + 40)

                    sh1.Range("M" & id).Value = file & "'!B" & (MonthNbr + 13) 'YTD KPI Index
                        Select Case sh1.Range("M" & id).Value
                        Case "R"
                        sh1.Range("M" & id).Value = "3"
                        Case "Y"
                        sh1.Range("M" & id).Value = "2"
                        Case "G"
                        sh1.Range("M" & id).Value = "1"
                        End Select

                    Range("N" & id) = "Values updated on " & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yy")

                    If Include3 = "%" Then              ' multiply with 100 for percentages

                    sh1.Range("D" & id).Value = (sh1.Range("D" & id).Value) * 100
                    sh1.Range("E" & id).Value = (sh1.Range("E" & id).Value) * 100
                    sh1.Range("F" & id).Value = (sh1.Range("F" & id).Value) * 100
                    sh1.Range("G" & id).Value = (sh1.Range("G" & id).Value) * 100
                    sh1.Range("I" & id).Value = (sh1.Range("I" & id).Value) * 100
                    sh1.Range("J" & id).Value = (sh1.Range("J" & id).Value) * 100
                    sh1.Range("K" & id).Value = (sh1.Range("K" & id).Value) * 100
                    sh1.Range("L" & id).Value = (sh1.Range("L" & id).Value) * 100

                    End If
                Else
                    Range("N" & id) = "Sheet available but segment missing"
                End If
            Else
                If Include2 = "no" Then
                    Range("N" & id) = "Metric set to not yet include"
                Else
                    If Include1 = "manual" Then Range("N" & id) = "Metric to be manually updated"
                End If
            End If
        Next id
   End With
    MsgBox "Update completed!"
End Sub
```