# Lookup stops at year change / range error

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have two sheets sheet1 "kintai_demo" [having 3 columns 'employeid' 'date' 'attendence' ) and sheet2 "kintai_test"(having 1st column 'employeid'[F8:F26] and dates[H6:AL6(2020/dec/21-2021/jan/20)].

I transfer data from kintai_demo to kintai_test by matching employeid and dates so their attendence shows in the sheet2 employid on the left dates on top left to right like [P, A, off, HD, etc.].

Doing it with lookat works till dec 31 and stops at 1st jan and gives error 91.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    '????
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim myRange_day As Range
    Dim myObj As Range
    Dim myObj_day As Range
          
    Dim myObj_emply As Range
    Dim keyWord As String
    Dim keyWord_day As String
    Dim date_range As Range
       
    Dim emplyObj As Range
    Dim keyWord_emply As String
        
    Set myRange = Sheets("kintai_test").Range("F8:F26")
    Set myRange_day = Sheets("kintai_test").Range("H6:AL6")
    Set myObj_emply = Sheets("kintai_test").Range("F8:F26")
        
    'For loop variable
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
             
    For i = 2 To 14
        '??????
        'Set myObj = myRange.Find(keyWord, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        For a = 8 To 36
            For j = 8 To 15
                keyWord = Sheets("kintai_demo").Cells(i, 1).Value
                keyWord_day = Sheets("kintai_demo").Cells(i, 2).Value
                keyWord_emply = Sheets("kintai_demo").Cells(i, 1).Value
        
                '(????)date search
                Set myObj_day = myRange_day.Find(What:=keyWord_day, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
                '(????)employe id search
                Set myObj_emply = myObj_emply.Find(What:=keyWord_emply, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
                'this line shows error 91
    
                Sheets("kintai_test").Cells(myObj_emply.Row, myObj_day.Column).Value = Sheets("kintai_demo").Cells(i, 3).Value
     
                i = i + 1
            Next j
        Next a
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: you have error because one of those variable `myObj_day  myObj_emply `  is nothing. If you use range.find method you should add condition to check is anything find like `if myObj_day   is nothing then ...`

Comment: i would really appriciatev it if you could please tell me what to write after then...?  i understood your point though

Answer (score 0):

I add conditions after each rng.find method. If range not found msgbox will be shown

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '????
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim myRange_day As Range
    Dim myObj As Range
    Dim myObj_day As Range
          
    Dim myObj_emply As Range
    Dim myObj_emply_found As Range
    Dim keyWord As String
    Dim keyWord_day As String
    Dim date_range As Range
       
       
    Dim emplyObj As Range
    Dim keyWord_emply As String
        
    Set myRange = Sheets("kintai_test").Range("F8:F26")
    Set myRange_day = Sheets("kintai_test").Range("H6:AL6")
    Set myObj_emply = Sheets("kintai_test").Range("F8:F26")
        
    'For loop variable
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
             
    For i = 2 To 14
        '??????
        'Set myObj = myRange.Find(keyWord, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        For a = 8 To 36
            For j = 8 To 15
                keyWord = Sheets("kintai_demo").Cells(i, 1).Value
                keyWord_day = Sheets("kintai_demo").Cells(i, 2).Value
                keyWord_emply = Sheets("kintai_demo").Cells(i, 1).Value
        
                '(????)date search
                Set myObj_day = myRange_day.Find(What:=keyWord_day, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                If myObj_day Is Nothing Then MsgBox "not found myObj_day ", vbCritical, "" 
                '(????)employe id search
                '   you cant use same variable to set range where you lookup and assign to him range found
                '   i add new variable myObj_emply_found
                Set myObj_emply_found = myObj_emply.Find(What:=keyWord_emply, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                If myObj_emply_found Is Nothing Then MsgBox "not found myObj_emply_found ", vbCritical, "" 
                'this line shows error 91
                'AND CONDITION TO DO IF BOTH FOUND
                If Not myObj_day Is Nothing And Not myObj_emply_found Is Nothing Then
                    Sheets("kintai_test").Cells(myObj_emply_found .Row, myObj_day.Column).Value = Sheets("kintai_demo").Cells(i, 3).Value
                End If
                i = i + 1
            Next j
        Next a
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: for future try use variables for workbooks and worksheets

Comment: i did this and the MsgBox "not found myObj_day" showed up and excel got hanged i just kept on cancelling it and it continued showing up which hanged the excel again and again so i forced shut down. any idea why this is happening i would really appriciate the advice thank you

Comment: change msgbox to debug.print like `debug.print "not found"& keyWord_day`. then you can open console and check every keyWord_day which is not found.

Comment: I really apologize for asking it again and again but it still it works  till dec 31 and stops at 1st jan and gives error 91

Comment: Now this is the situation If myObj_day Is Nothing Then Debug.Print "not found" & keyWord_day; ", vbCritical, """  so its showing this on all january dates but works perfect with december dates not found2021/01/04, vbCritical, " not found2021/01/05, vbCritical, " not found2021/01/06, vbCritical, "

Comment: if `myRange_day` cells values are Data type u will not find string type variable `keyWord_day` with cells.find method. change type declaration for this variable `dim keyWord_day as Date` and make sure `myRange_day` iclude data types cells values

Comment: by changing dim keyword_day as Date the error shows not found0:00:00, vbCritical, " and does not copy data at all. but with set to string capy till dec 30 2020 but do not copy for jan 2021. cell value in myrange_day is date like 2021/1/1

Comment: 1. error is shown because you try assign value to date type variable which is not date type, if you want search date type you need convert value from cell to date type

Comment: 2. string type variable works by accident for other months because format of  variable. it will not work searching string type variable in date type base.

Comment: check similar topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980484/checking-data-types-in-a-range

Comment: Thank you very much for your constant advice i really appreciate it.